# in VBA For loop stops executing after around 530 iterations

Tags: excel, vba

I have written simple code for my job related tasks, but it stops executing without any error message on 530 iteration, while I still have some data left that should be processed.

Tried to delete all code in VBA and paste it in from Notepad. Tried debugger. Tried restarting excel and pc.

```
Function CoRow() As Long
    CoRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Sub Sort()
    Dim LastNace As Integer
    Dim NextNace As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    LastNace = Cells(2, "C").Value
    NextNace = Cells(3, "C").Value
    Columns("A:E").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("E2"), Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
    For i = 1 To CoRow
        If LastNace <> NextNace And LastNace <> 0 And NextNace <> 0 And i <> 1 Then
            Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf LastNace <> NextNace And LastNace <> 0 And NextNace = 0 And i <> 1 Then
            Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            i = i + 1
        End If
        LastNace = Cells(i + 1, "C").Value
        NextNace = Cells(i + 2, "C").Value
        'Range(Cells(i + 1, 3).Address(), Cells(i + 1, 3).Address()).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Expected result is that goes beyond 530 iterations. I suspect there is something wrong with sort, as it sort also same number of rows, before this code is executed.

Comment: You are inserting rows and making repeated calls to coRow - was that your intention? You are using implicit activesheet references all over the place which is bug prone - you should add the sheet names in front of Cells/Range (or wrap the whole thing in a With statement and use the dot operator e.g. .Cells). Avoid .Select and use Long instead  of Integer.

Comment: Yes. CoRow recalulates how many rows are in my table after I have inserted new ones. This code is activated by button on sheet data is, but you are right that I should add sheet names. I need Selection.Sort to sort my data.

Comment: You can determine the range and use that for your sort as opposed to use .Select

Comment: I have changed main procedure as follows: 
    ...
    
    Sheets("Imp").Range("A:E").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("E2"), Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal

            However it still does not run beyond 530 iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your recalculation of `CoRow` doesn't effect the end of the loop!

Note that in `For` loops, once the loop is started

```
For i = 1 To CoRow
```

any value change of `CoRow` does **not affect the end of the loop**! The `For` loop always uses the value of `CoRow` that was set when the loop started.

Following example:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim iEnd As Long
iEnd = 10

For i = 1 To iEnd
    iEnd = 20 'this has NO EFFECT on the end of the For loop
    Debug.Print i, iEnd
Next i
```

This loob will only run from `1 … 10` because once the loop started with `For i = 1 To iEnd` any change of `iEnd = 20` doesn't affect the end of the loop.

---

#### Solution

Replace it with a `Do` loop.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim iEnd As Long
iEnd = 10

i = 1 'initialization needed before Do loops

Do While i <= iEnd
    iEnd = 20
    Debug.Print i, iEnd

    i = i + 1 'manual increase of counter needed in the end of Do loops
Loop
```

Note that for `Do` loops you need to initialize your counter `i = 1` and also increase it manually `i = i + 1`. This time the change of `iEnd = 20` take effect and the loop runs from `1 … 20` because the `Do` loop evaluates the condition `i <= iEnd` on **every** iteration (not only on the start as the `For` loop does).

#### Alternative

Another solution (if you insert or delete rows) is to run the loop backwards:

```
Dim CoRow As Long 'make it a variable not a function then
CoRow = Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
For i = CoRow To 1 Step -1
    'runs backwards starting at the last row ending at the first
Next i
```

But if this is possible or not depends on your data and what actions you perform within the loop.

---

#### Improvement

Note that this `CoRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` will eat up some time. Instead of making `CoRow` a function make it a variable and just increase it by 1 `CoRow = CoRow + 1` every time you insert a row, which will be much faster than determining the last row over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I implemented a lot from your suggestions and now this code does what I wanted it to do. :)

```
Function CoRow() As Long
CoRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Sub Sort()
Dim LastNace As Integer
Dim NextNace As Integer
Dim CountNace As Integer
Dim r As Long
Dim i As Long
Sheets("Imp").Range("A:E").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("E2"), Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
LastNace = Sheets("Imp").Cells(2, "C").Value
NextNace = Sheets("Imp").Cells(3, "C").Value
r = CoRow
CountNace = 0
For i = 1 To r
    If LastNace <> NextNace And LastNace <> 0 And NextNace <> 0 Then
        CountNace = CountNace + 1
    End If
    LastNace = Sheets("Imp").Cells(i + 1, "C").Value
    NextNace = Sheets("Imp").Cells(i + 2, "C").Value
Next
r = r + CountNace
LastNace = Sheets("Imp").Cells(2, "C").Value
NextNace = Sheets("Imp").Cells(3, "C").Value
For i = 1 To r
    If LastNace <> NextNace And LastNace <> 0 And NextNace <> 0 And i <> 1 Then
        Sheets("Imp").Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheets("Imp").Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf LastNace <> NextNace And LastNace <> 0 And NextNace = 0 And i <> 1 Then
        Sheets("Imp").Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheets("Imp").Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        i = i + 1
    End If
    LastNace = Sheets("Imp").Cells(i + 1, "C").Value
    NextNace = Sheets("Imp").Cells(i + 2, "C").Value
    'Sheets("Imp").Range(Cells(i + 1, 3), Cells(i + 1, 3)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that I suggest to read my answer again. What you did (looping twice) takes a lot of time and is very inefficient. I recommend to keep it one loop and replace the `For` loop with a `Do` loop and your code should get a lot faster.